# limiting the LOGS in spaek with Scala code

Tags: scala, apache-spark, logging, bigdata

I have installed spark 3.3.0 version installed in my PC. I want to limit the logs to show only the error logs in the console for that I have used

> Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

I am still getting info logs in the console

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j2-defaults.properties
22/10/21 18:04:39 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.3.0
22/10/21 18:04:39 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
22/10/21 18:04:39 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
22/10/21 18:04:39 INFO ResourceUtils: No custom resources configured for spark.driver.
22/10/21 18:04:39 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
22/10/21 18:04:39 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: My first assignment
22/10/21 18:04:40 INFO ResourceProfile: Default ResourceProfile created, executor resources: Map(cores -> name: cores, amount: 1, script: , vendor: , memory -> name: memory, amount: 1024, script: , vendor: , offHeap -> name: offHeap, amount: 0, script: , vendor: ), task resources: Map(cpus -> name: cpus, amount: 1.0)
22/10/21 18:04:40 INFO ResourceProfile: Limiting resource is cpu
```

how should I control these logs. I am new to spark

Comment: Controlling log level from the code works but it's likely executed a bit after initialization of other things like Spark, thus it's better to configure log level from the config file which be loaded first.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your spark-3.3.0/conf/log4j.properties from:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console
```

to

```
log4j.rootCategory=WARN, console
```

If the log4j.properties doesn't exist, use:

```
cp spark-3.3.0/conf/log4j.properties.template spark-3.3.0/conf/log4j.properties.template
```

Comment: I am working in windows and I am writing my code in scala

my spark located directory is C:\bigdata\spark\conf

and I don't have log4j.properties instead I have log4j2.properties.template

by in my console after execution it is showing Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j2-defaults.properties

Comment: Okay. Some things might be different based on spark version (i use 3.2.1). Were you able to copy the template and change the level in it?